# Why do I get an import error for zmq but only from command line?

Tags: python, command-line, zeromq, importerror

Well the subject says it all. I can run the same file in pycharm without problems.

Putting `import zmq` in a file reproduces it. Never had a problem with zmq before running the program from command line.

Comment: You've setup PyCharm to use a different interpreter

Answer (score 1):

The reported problem probably means that you do not use the same python interpreter in terminal and pycharm.

If you call `python` and have the import error, you can install `pyzmq` for your python interpreter with command.

```
python -m pip install pyzmq
```

Comment: i don't think that was it,  had zmq both installed globally and in the virtualenv i used in pycharm

Answer (score 0):

i have actually solved it by using the -m option: `>python -m`, I would like to know  why that worked.